# In what sense is (# a #), the one-element unboxed tuple, different from 'a'?

Tags: haskell

In [`Data.Primitive.SmallArray`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive-0.7.1.0/docs/Data-Primitive-SmallArray.html#v:indexSmallArray-35--35-), there's the function:

```
indexSmallArray## :: SmallArray a -> Int -> (#a#)
```

It returns its result in a one-element [unboxed tuple](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=unboxedtuples#extension-UnboxedTuples).

My question is: what do we gain from returning the unboxed tuple? Why not return simply `a`?

I do get the usefulness of unboxed tuples of more than one element. As the [Levity Polymorphism](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/levity-pldi17.pdf) paper says:

> Originally conceived to support returning multiple values from a
> function, an unboxed tuple is merely Haskell syntax for tying multiple
> values together. Unboxed tuples do not exist at runtime, at all
> [...] during compilation, the unboxed tuple is erased completely

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that the aim is to decouple the work of indexing into the array from "forcing" `a` itself to WHNF.

If we simply returned `a`, then evaluating a call to `indexSmallArray##` to WHNF would both perform the indexing *and* evaluate the result to WHNF.

Pattern-matching on `(# a #)` will perform the indexing (thus freeing the reference to the array hiding behind the thunk, potentially allowing the array to be garbage-collected)  but does not force the single component `a` to WHNF (it could be `undefined` for all we know).

In the [docs](https://github.com/andrewthad/ghc/blob/3f7c4d8e8882ec23681e85fa3f5f259abd93338f/compiler/prelude/primops.txt.pp#L819) of a primop that uses a similar technique, we find:

> primop  IndexArrayOp "indexArray#" GenPrimOp
> Array# a -> Int# -> (#> a #)
> {Read from specified index of immutable array. Result is
> packaged into
> an unboxed unary tuple; the result itself is not yet evaluated. Pattern
> matching on the tuple forces the indexing of the array
> to happen but does not evaluate the element itself. Doing this
> pattern match immidiately can be useful for (1) preventing
> additional thunks from building up on the heap and (2) eliminating
> references to the argument array, allowing it to be garbage
> collected more promptly.}

I guess we could accomplish the same using a wrapper type like `data Wrap a = Wrap a`, but this would cause unnecessary heap allocations, which don't happen with the unboxed tuple.

Comment: There's also `indexSmallArrayM`, which lets you index in the context of any `Monad` (really, it should be any `Applicative`), including your hypothetical `Wrap`. There was an accepted GHC proposal to expose something like your `Wrap`, but I'm not exactly sure where it ended up or what it's called, and it's not much used as yet.

Comment: The `Solo` type has a similar purpose, although it's boxed instead of unboxed like `(# #)`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Data-Tuple.html#t:Solo